# how to rig a car engine piston

Tags: rigging, constraints, drivers

i need some help setting up what is basically the same as a piston in a car engine's cylinder. i know i can just use keyframes and NLA strips but im after a more dynamic approach that wont require a bunch of edits to change the speed or phase. ideally i want to connect the rotation to the up and down motion of the control handle im using for the rest of the parts but i am stumped.
i have animation nodes installed so solutions using that are also viable. suggestions appreciated as im at my wits end.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Piston.gif

Comment: @AlienXtream.. if you're still having difficulty, post a minimal, stripped-down version of the mechanism in place on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, and I'll get to it.

Comment: @RobinBetts oh. sorry. didn't notice that comment till after i made a drop box file. im still new to navigating this site >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with one driver and one look-at constraint.

The height of the piston-pin above the center of the crank is given by the following expression:

`h = r * cos(A)+sqrt( (l**2)-( (r**2)*(sin(A)**2) )  )`

where `r` is the radius of the crank, `l` is the length of the rod, and `A` is the rotation of the crank, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piston_motion_equations).

With a crank of radius 1, and a rod of length 4, as illustrated, this reduces to:

`sqrt(16-(sin(A)**2))+cos(A)`

so this is the sort of expression you can put into a driver for the height of the piston(-pin), where A is the angle through which the crank is rotated.

The rod simply has to be parented to the crank, with its origin on the crank's circumference, and given a *Locked Track* constraint, making it look at the piston-pin.

[image]

If you parent both the piston-pin and the crank to another object, their transforms are evaluated in that object's space, and so the rig can be freely moved around, using their parent. In the example blendfile, it's the Empty called 'Basis'.

[image]

Comment: this is ALMOST what i need and the math is indeed what i was after however the example you provided is fixed at the world origin and i can not get my head around it enough to jury rig it into my scene. thank you for the reply none the less. it may not "resolve" the problem but its certainly put me on the right track to try and solve myself. i will continue messing with it untill either i work it out or someone here posts another approach (or an addendum to yours). again, thanks for the pointers :)

Comment: ok, so i have the tracking, rotation driving and parenting all set but i cant seem to get the equation to behave right. at present the motion itself is correct but the piston pin is moving in the ranges of 2m where as the desired range is 7cm (0.07m). how do i alter the equation to account for an arbitrary diameter "crank"?

Comment: im sorry, im not sure i get what you mean? the size of my crank is a diameter 0.07m (r 0.035) and my piston arm is 0.10517 m between the 2 pivots. i edited the equation to what i assume is the r and L variables resulting in this 
"sqrt(0.105-(sin(A)**0.035))+cos(A)" but blender just gives a python error in the driver and so i dont know what to do :( i can try and isolate the part and send a blend file over  for you to look at and tell me what im doing wrong if that would help

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cznil15s83x7x3/Brass.blend3.blend?dl=0 ok, there's a dropbox link to the stripped blend file.

Comment: you're under no obligation to, thus making me all the more grateful for the help :)

Comment: @AlienXtream   OK, I hope [this suits](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/nyMAosP4/) .. In general, I find it's better to construct and test rigs at World 0, an then parent everything to move to the working location. You don't want offsets finding their way into expressions. You _could_ add more variables to the driver, to allow variable crank size, etc.. but that's more for general asset creation, and there's a (small) computational cost.

Comment: thankyou SO much, it works exactly as needed. had a quick look but later i will work on implementing it into the original. the scene wasn't something i planned ahead on much and so at the time i had no idea what i was going to need setup. not the best way to go i know but it works for me 99% of the time. again, thankyou SO much for the help

Comment: here it is. i felt i should share the final product with you as a small token of gratitude. you basically did the heavy lifting after all, its the least i can do :)
https://imgur.com/a/KI5GUux

Comment: @AlienXtream Great! Case closed. And thanks for sharing the result. It's nice to see where stuff goes. Your Q. also got me to fish a very rusty tool from the bottom of my box: the generalisation of Pythagoras which is the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). So thank you, too.